# How to fix ERR_REQUIRE_ESM when I try to start an azure application?

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have deployed my node application in azure, but I can't figure out how to solve this error:

> Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:Error
> [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js
> from C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js not
> supported.Instead change the require of app.js in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js to a dynamic import() which is available
> in all CommonJS modules.at Object. (C:\Program Files
> (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)

All the solution states that I have to add

> "type": "module"

in the package.json file and change require to import, but I already did that.
Also, I can't find this iisnode folder, neither the interceptor.js file.

I followed this guide to deploy my app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-express-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "description": "my-express-app",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^1.16.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "tedious": "^15.1.2",
    "tedious-connection-pool": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import logger from "morgan";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as checkResource from "./middleware/checkResource.js";
import { setError } from "./middleware/error.js";
import cors from "cors";

import { router as routes_Admin } from "./controllers/admin.js";
import { resolve } from "path";

export var app = express();

// middlewares
app.use(checkResource.check);
app.use(setError);
app.use("/static", express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//controllers;
app.use(routes_Admin);

app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello World!");
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {});
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the app.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure that IISnode is installed correctly, and then try to republish your application, and here is a same error you can use as a reference: [https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues/90](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues/90).

Comment: Try this to enable experimental support for ESM modules by adding the --experimental-modules flag to the "start"

 "scripts": {
  "start": "node --experimental-modules app.js"
}

Comment: Update: yesterday I changed node version to 14 and also converted esm in cjs. But now I have a problem connecting to my on-premise sql server db with this error: 

**500 - Error: Failed to connect to [ip_address]:1433 - Could not connect (sequence).**

This won't work only when the app is deployed on cloud.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.